# What tools are currently available or in development, to watch an address, and expose a bad actor that without authorization took ADA from a wallet?

Tags: wallet, ada, private-key, seed-phrase, atala-prism

Despite that the legitimate owner of a given amount of ADA in a wallet went loose on keeping hxs account secure, and the saying "No your keys no your ADA", when a bad actor takes ADA not authorized by the ADA owner, the bad actor has to use one of his wallet's receiving addresses. This is an immutable fact that will stay forever in the blockchain.

Using tools like Cardanoscan.io for example, one can trace and watch that wallet to see what other information has on it, * what transactions have occurred, * what is on each transaction, - i.e. NFTs-, to what pool it is delegating to, what have been purchased with that ADA, or if nothing has been done with the ADA, then watch it closely.
Additional Tags: Reputation. Bad-Actor

Answer (score 1):

> the bad actor has to use one of his wallet's receiving addresse

This is not completly true, there are tools called "[mixers](https://fortune.com/2022/03/26/what-are-crypto-mixers/)", that obfuscates the destination address of transactions.
This will make really difficult to understand in which wallet they arrive.

Also another related point is the fact that, if the attacker did everything good, it will be difficult to trace his identity and then to persue him legally.

In any case, it would also be impossible to restore the funds without the attacker's private key, so it is better to focus on how to keep a wallet safe instead of try to trace funds that are already lost and can't be restored (this is just my opinion).

Comment: you have a valid point on focusing in keeping a wallet safe; still, even if the funds cannot be recovered, it is always worth to explore options that clear the road for authorities to persecute this type of attackers. I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding tools, well there are in random order:

- https://cardanoscan.io/ (like you already mentioned)
- https://explorer.cardano.org/
- https://cexplorer.io/

And soon a light wallet: https://lace.io

But I think the use-case of bad actors was never the main goal of any of those products. But any of those websites could maybe help you.

In any case, store your crypto safe. Use a hardware wallet.

Comment: Thanks @Melroy van den Berg. Yes, a cold wallet is the go to for safety.